# Export and import mysql at the same time on different servers

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I am using AWS RDS and wish to backup my primary db hourly to a DR site in another region

What I need is a mysql command which will export the db and import into another mysql server running in a different location

I am looking into using something like the following

$ mysqldump -umy_user -pmy_pass_1 -R my_database my_table | mysql -umy_user -pmy_pass_2 my_database

However I cannot seem to specify a host for the export db, how can I acheieve this?

I also need to consider security so would like this over SSL, any idea?

[edit]: got this sort of working by the following process

On a linux node in my primary site ran a mysqldump and then ran a mysql command to import into the dr site e.g.

mysqldump -P 3306 -h primary.com -u user --password=pass mydb > test.sql;

mysql -P 3306 -h dr.com -u user --password=pass mydb < test.sql;

However I still need this to be secure

Comment: Anything here helpful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ssl-connections.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqldump` accepts `ssl` arguments:

```
--ssl               Enable SSL for connection (automatically enabled with
                    other flags).
--ssl-ca=name       CA file in PEM format (check OpenSSL docs, implies
                    --ssl).
--ssl-capath=name   CA directory (check OpenSSL docs, implies --ssl).
--ssl-cert=name     X509 cert in PEM format (implies --ssl).
--ssl-cipher=name   SSL cipher to use (implies --ssl).
--ssl-key=name      X509 key in PEM format (implies --ssl).
--ssl-verify-server-cert 
                    Verify server's "Common Name" in its cert against
                    hostname used when connecting. This option is disabled by
                    default.
```

Set up the proper certs and it should be straightforward. Good details are [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-ssl-connections.html).